# Show pop up div on page load using code behind in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, code-behind

I have a condition in which i want to show the pop up div on page load, depending on querystring. like if query string **delete=1** then i need to open the pop up. I am using the modal pop up from the following link:

[SimpleModal Demos](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) i am using the **OSX Style Dialog**, Please help me.

my code behind code is

```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["delete"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["u"]))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "test", "$('#osx-modal-content').modal({overlayId: 'osx-overlay',containerId: 'osx-container', closeHTML: null,minHeight: 80,opacity: 65, position: ['0',],overlayClose: true, onOpen: OSX.open,onClose: OSX.close }); ", true);
    }
```

Comment: @sqve please study the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User modal function in the osx.js file and call it from code behind using the page.registerstartupscript

Comment: i have tried the way have suggested but its not working for me please see my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

one answer is above other in javasript function pageload(){  //Read query string 
$(#div).show();
}  by this you can show up div as pop during pageload.

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you using the ModalPopupExtender included in the ASP.net AJAX Control Toolkit?